# Returning true once instead of multiple times in a for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I want to create a function that takes in an array and returns true if the array is an arithmetic series and returns false if it is not. My problem is my for loop is looping through each pair to see if each consecutive pair is divisible by the difference of the first two elements. As a consequence, I am stuck and can only create a function that returns true 4 times when I do have a arithmetic series. Does anyone know how to alter my code so that I only get true or false. Here's what I have:

```
function arithseries(arr){
    var arit = arr[1] - arr[0];
    for(var i = 0; i < (arr.length - 1); i++){
        if((arr[i + 1] - arr[i]) % arit === 0){
            console.log("true");
            }
        else{
            console.log("false")
        }
        }
    }


arithseries([2,4,6,8,10])
```

returns

```
=> true
=> true
=> true
=> true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function arithseries(arr) {
    var arit = arr[1] - arr[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < (arr.length - 1); i++) {
        if ((arr[i + 1] - arr[i]) % arit !== 0){
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}


console.log(arithseries([2,4,6,8,10]))
```

Comment: Why did you remove `else`?

Comment: In the else branch you'd actually say 'okay, everything fine so far - continue testing'. You check each element and as soon as one is wrong, you return `false` (series not correct). When you checked all elements (i.e. after the for loop) you know that the series is valid and return `true`. No need for an else anywhere since the loop will continue anyway.

Comment: Right, but what if the `if` conditional returns false once the loop has stopped wont it also move on from the for loop and return true as well?